# C# WPF check if checkbox is checked error

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

When I do:

```
if (checkbox1.IsChecked)
```

I get the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'.

When I do:

```
if (checkbox1.Checked)
```

I get the error:

> "The event 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.Checked' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=".

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is good information for others who has that issue, so i believe i should keep the question, why do you downvote it? is it really the formatting/grammar error from Stackoverflow which is not my fault, but most likely caused by copying the program error messages, that triggers you?

Comment: A tip on the road to writing good questions is to not include useless noise (like greetings, or signatures) in your question. Keep it straight and to the point. This isn't a social forum, it's a Q&A site.

Comment: Another tip is to capitalise your personal "I". This is the way to do it in english and the site will see it as a sign of low quality if you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IsChecked` is a nullable boolean, which means it can have three states.  Nullable types are denoted by the `?` you see in the error.

Try this:

```
if ((bool)checkbox1.IsChecked == true)
```